# JSON Object XHR and closures

Tags: javascript, json, closures, xmlhttprequest

I have a JSON object that is populated by an XHR. I then need to update that object with values from a separate XHR call. The issue I am running into is the second call isn't being made at the correct time and I think it's an issue with how I structured my object. Here is what I have:

```
function Proprietary()
{
  var proprietary= this;
  this.Groups = {};
  this.getGroups = function()
  {
    $.getJSON(group_url,   function(data){proprietary.callReturned(data);});

  }


  this.callReturned = function(data)
  {
   //Do stuff
   for(var i=0; i< data.groups.length; i++)
   {
    insparq.Groups[i] = data.groups[i];
    $.getJSON(participant_url, function(p){proprietary.Groups[i].participants = p;});
    }

//the function call below is the action I want to occur after the object is populated. 
   PopulateGroups();
  }

};
```

Comment: I think that you naming a variable called `proprietary` within a function called `proprietary` could cause some issues, don't you think?

Comment: `PopulateGroups` is being called BEFORE all the `$.getJSON(participant_url ...` are. You need to check how many participats you load by using an external counter and checking it against the size of `proprietary.Groups` inside the `$.getJSON(participant_url ...` callback function and only when they're equal should you call `PopulateGroups`.

Comment: Thank you, Horia. Where/how would increment the counter?

Comment: You can use `$.ajax` instead of `$.getJSON` because you can set `async: false` to enable sync ajax call which would resolve you issue immediately.

Comment: @Kevin Using synchronous ajax calls would lock up the browser while it attempts to fetch the data - not a very good idea

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be a number of weird things in that code snippet.

First of all, $.getJSON(...) takes a third parameter, which is your callback.  The second parameter is data.  I think you are passing a function as your data parameter.  You will need to fix this in both places.  If you don't need to pass anything, just have your second parameter be an empty object {}.

Here's one general way you can execute a callback after ALL of your XMLHttpRequests have come back from the server.

```
this.callReturned = function(data) {

    var countdown = data.groups.length;
    function callback() {
        if(countdown-- === 1) {
            PopulateGroups();
        }
    }

    for(var i=0; i< data.groups.length; i++)
    {
        insparq.Groups[i] = data.groups[i];
        $.getJSON(participant_url, { /* data to send to server */ }, callback);
    }

}
```

In this snippet, the callback function is executed each time you get a XMLHttpRequest back from the server.  The last one executes PopulateGroups(), after the countdown descends to 1 from data.groups.length.